# How to scroll inside a dialog window with playwright python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, playwright, playwright-python

I'm facing a problem. After clicking an element, a `dialog` floating window appears containing some comments that I want to retreive, but after many intents to scrolling down inside that dialog window, I just couldn't. I try selecting the `div` that contains all dialog window and then execute a `.evaluate()` but didn't work. I tried using `page.mouse.move(0,0)` and `page.mouse.wheel(0,50)` but neither worked. How can I scroll down inside this dialog window?
This is my code:

```
class PlaywrightScraper:
    def __init__(self):
        self.options = options #Basic options to launch Chromium
        self.logger = Logger()
        self.cookiesService = CookiesFacebookService() # Retrieve my Facebook Cookie from a database
        self.log = self.logger.getLogger(self.__class__.__name__)

    @staticmethod # Parse cookie to a cookie-object to load in playwright
    def set_cookie_fb(cookies):
        list_keys_cookies = []
        for key, value in cookies.items():
            cookie_req = {
                "path": "/",
                "domain": ".facebook.com",
                "sameSite": "Lax",
                "name": key,
                "httpOnly": True,
                "secure": True,
                "value": value
            }
            list_keys_cookies.append(cookie_req)
        return list_keys_cookies

    def prepare_launch_browser(self):
        try:
            with sync_playwright() as playwright:
                return self.launch_playwright(playwright=playwright, options_browser=self.options)
        except Exception as ex0:
            print(f"Error launching Playwright: {repr(ex0)}", traceback.format_exc())

    def launch_playwright(self, playwright, options_browser):
        user_cookies = self.cookiesService.getAccountFacebook()[0]["reqCookies"]
        browser = playwright.chromium.launch(**options_browser)
        page = browser.new_page()
        page.context.add_cookies(self.set_cookie_fb(user_cookies))
        page.goto("https://www.facebook.com/groups/243471969040197", wait_until='load')
        try:
            page.on("response", self.filter_comment_response)
            load_more_comments = page.query_selector('span[dir="auto"]:has-text("Ver más comentarios")')
            if load_more_comments is not None:
                load_more_comments.click()
                page.wait_for_load_state('load')
                comment_new_height_popup = 0
                counter_paginate_comment = 0
                comment_previous_height_popup = 100
                pop_up = page.query_selector("//div[@role=\"dialog\"]")
                while comment_new_height_popup != comment_previous_height_popup and counter_paginate_comment <= MAX_PAGINATE_COMMENTS:
                    pop_up.evaluate("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")
                    counter_paginate_comment += 1
                    comment_new_height_popup = page.evaluate("document.body.scrollHeight")
                    if comment_new_height_popup == comment_previous_height_popup:
                        break
                    comment_previous_height_popup = comment_new_height_popup
                page.remove_listener("response", self.filter_comment_response)
                paginated_comments = self.list_of_paginated_comments # List of paginated comments
            else:
                page.remove_listener("response", self.filter_comment_response)
                paginated_comments = []
        except Exception as ex2:
            self.log.error(f"No hay más comentarios. {repr(ex2)}", traceback.format_exc())
            paginated_comments = []


    def filter_comment_response(self, response):
        if response.request.method == "POST" and "api/graphql" in response.request.url:
            try:
                text_body = response.body().decode('utf-8')
                final_text = re.sub(r'\n', ",", text_body)
                list_of_json = json.loads("[" + final_text + "]")
                clean_list = [x for x in list_of_json if "created_comment_insertion_position" in str(x)]
                self.list_of_paginated_comments.extend(clean_list)
            except Exception as ex0:
                self.log.error(f"Error catching graphql requests for comments: {repr(ex0)}", traceback.format_exc())
```

I need to capture network traffic while scrolling down to get comments, because HTML is very, very large.

The `dialog` floating window is inside many `div` elements and inside the body of the general page.

I have added a minimum reproducible example, you just need to format your facebook cookie as a json object and load it. For the example, I use a public group, what I want is use any post with +20 comments, make click in `Load more comments` and then in the floating window, scrolling down catching network traffic to retrieve comments instead of using the HTML (which is more difficult in my opinion), then click in `Load more comments` inside that window if necessary and close when the bottom is reached.